# Optimize time to execute chained API calls in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making 3rd party API calls in order to save and use the registered user details to create records on each one of the API platforms. In order to do that, I need to fetch the data from one API call and use that data (a property of the data) to make the next API call in Nodejs. For this, I am using fetch() along with Promise as shown in the code sample below.

```
// Call the API
fetch('url1').then(function (response) {
    if (!response.ok) return Promise.reject(response);
    return response.json();
}).then(function (url1Response) {
    // Store the url1 response data to a variable for futher use (if required)
    newdata = url1Response;
    return fetch('url2'); // use a property of the first api response to execute next API call.
}).then(function (response) {
    if (!response.ok) return Promise.reject(response);
    return response.json();
}).then(function (url2Response) {
    console.log(newdata, url1Response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.warn(error);
});
```

My code execution is working but it is taking too long time to execute and send the response at last, So I want to optimize the time for execution.

Is there any way to do to execute this in a very optimized way so that the time complexity will be as minimum as possible? It will be great if any node module is there to solve this.

Comment: Only the actual fetches in that code take a long time (unless you've elided some complex computation here).

Comment: if it's your server you're fetching from, then, fix the server code (if it's taking longer than it **could**) - if it's not your server, then the fetch will take as long as it takes, nothing you can do about it - anyway ... `taking too long` - how "long" is too long?

Comment: @AKX No Such complex computation is there just using a property of the previous API response to make the next one.

Comment: @Bravo All the API calls will be 3 parties such that I personally can't do anything on that side. I have the option either to improve the code or make the API calls in a way that needs minimum execution time.

Comment: if an API call depends on the previous API call then there is no optimization for the code you've shown - none at all - how can there be? since call 2 needs to wait for call 1 - what is "too long"

Comment: You probably can't materially improve the time Node.js takes to do a `fetch()`, so there's not much you can do here.

Comment: Guys, it took approximately around 8 to 10 secs or more to execute and gives us the result.